# Hanuman Chest Writing

Tags: hanuman, identification-request

Ram Ram brothers and sisters

I’m relatively new to Hinduism so I was just wondering if someone could tell me what is written on Hanuman’s chest in this picture, I can’t seem to find any information online about it. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ram is written on Hanuman's chest. It is written in Devanagri Script.

It is  the name of the seventh Avatar of Vishnu who is one of the three major gods of Hinduism the other two being Bramha and Shiva (Mahesh) who are collectively called as Bramha-Vishnu-Mahesh.

Rama is also the hero of the Hindu epic Ramayana in which after being exiled by his father King Dashrath of Ayodhya due to the two boons given to Kaikeyi who is the favorite queen of King Dashrath. She asks for the two boons, of which the first is that Rama should be put to 14 years if exile and the second one being that her son Bharat being made the King (Rama was the eldest son so he was the legitimate heir.)

Rama goes into exile with his wife Sita and brother Lakshman. While in exile he meets Hanuman who is his greatest devotee and also an avatar of Shiva. While in exile his wife is kidnapped by Raavana who is the Demon King of Lanka. So Rama fights a war with him and kills him and frees his wife Sita from him.

Comment: To be exact, it says राम which is correctly transliterated to Rāma

Answer (score 3):

Ram is written on the chest of Hanuman in the above picture.

Comment: Thank you, sorry if I offended you with my lack of knowledge I was just curious

Comment: No worries, I too doesn't have much knowledge. Cheers.